# how to chech in ZF2 if controller and action exist or not

Tags: zend-framework2

how to check in ZF2 in controller, if controller and action exists or not?
My controller has to check, if the specified controller and action, with which he can create a widget, exists.
Thank.

Comment: If you're already "in" the controller, it doesn't make sense to check if it's a valid controller right? Can you elaborate on the use case?

Comment: using example: https://github.com/dphn/ScContent/blob/master/src/ScContent/Controller/FrontController.php With this config i have to add modules (widgets modules) https://github.com/dphn/ScContent/blob/master/config/sccontent.global.php.dist

Answer (score 2):

The controller is accessible via the controller's service locator. You can check the controller loader if an instance if available. If so, you create that instance and check if the action is a valid method.

In code:

```
// Inside your controller

protected function validateDispatchable($controller, $action)
{
    $loader = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ControllerLoader');
    if (!$loader->has($controller)) {
        return false; // No controller
    }

    $obj    = $loader->get($controller);
    $method = $obj::getMethodFromAction($action);

    if (!method_exists($obj, $method)) {
        return false; // No action
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the isDispatchable - Method of the front controller by passing it a Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract instance.

```
if( $front->getDispatcher()->isDispatchable($testRequest) )  
{  
    //Do somthing
}
```

Comment: You're referring to ZF1, the question is about ZF2

Comment: You do not carefully read the question. 2 versions of this will not work. But thanks anyway.